# Can anyone explain use of Driver Factory and its implementation to get parallel browser at same time?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium-grid

When do we need to create a Driver Factory ? What advantages do we get over regular initialisation of driver when we use driver factory approach.

Also how to initiate parallel browser testing using Driver factory.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea of running Selenium test in parallel is ensuring that there are no clashes and [race conditions](https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/race-condition) between WebDriver instances. The common practice is implementing [Thread Local Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) pattern in order to isolate WebDrivers and other data which is not [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)

WebDriver by design is not thread safe so if you intend to have several threads to run different webdriver instances you need to wrap them into [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) and most probably the "DriverFactory" you're talking about is a helper class which initializes webdriver puts it to ThreadLocal.

Check out [Parallel Tests - Best Practices](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices) for comprehensive information, tips, tricks and sample projects.

Answer (score 0):

DriverFactory (different implementations can be found [here](http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-factory-design-pattern-using-java-8-supplier/) and [here](https://github.com/FriendlyTester/WebDriverFactoryExample/blob/master/WebDriverDriverFactory/WebDriverDriverFactory/WebDriverFactory.cs), or [here](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/using_selenium_webdriver_katalon_studio.html#driverfactory) for Katalon Studio version) acts like a switch statement when you are working with multiple browsers.

It is just like the regular initialization, just more flexible, since you can tell your test where the driver is located / which driver is being used.